# How to unpack the Fortigate firmware?

Tags: firmware, binwalk

I want to unpack the fortigate firmware - `FGT_110C-v400-build0092-FORTINET.out`. `binwalk` only gives a hint about `gzip` compressed data.

```
~/Documents# binwalk -i FGT_110C-v400-build0092-FORTINET.out 

DECIMAL     HEXADECIMAL    DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0            0x0         gzip compressed data, has original file name: 
                           "FG110C-4.00-FW-build092-090220-patch00", from Unix,
                           last modified: Fri Feb 20 18:00:29 2009
```

These is no other output. How can I unpack the firmware?

I uploaded the firmware [here](http://www52.zippyshare.com/v/7RyFqBJy/file.html).

Comment: With gzip? It looks like you're on Windows, so you could also try 7z which supports gzip decompression too.

Comment: it is on linux,with the binwalk, and the binwalk output is gzip compressed data.  I upload the bin these http://www52.zippyshare.com/v/7RyFqBJy/file.html

Comment: How does the `patch00` file relate to the `.out` file you are talking about. I downloaded it, it seems very regular, if you make a hexdump of 64 bytes wide, you will notice. Probably it is xorred with a fixed 64 byte string.

Answer (score 1):

Main part of fortigate firmware is a `/bin/init` executable, most of other files are just symbolic links to it. So, you can obtain this file (or any other file of interest) from device or VM using `fnsysctl` and `exec backup` commands, together with the configured tftp-server. In my case it looks like this:

```
#> fnsysctl cp /bin/init /var/log/root/mlog.0
#> exec backup disk log tftp AA.BB.CC.DD anomaly
```

Then, rename the received file on the tftp-server.

Answer (score -1):

**binwalk -e** extracts it just fine.

You'll need https://github.com/sviehb/jefferson though, later.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? why is  the `-e` flag useful? etc.

Comment: Because it tells binwalk to extract? These are basics:
`-e, --extract                Automatically extract known file types`

Comment: Can you include that as part of your answer?